# Is it possible to use @html.EditorFor template that would in tern use another editorfor with ViewData.ModelMetadata

Tags: templates, asp.net-mvc-5, infragistics, ignite-ui

I'm trying to EditorFor template to display an Infragistic's control like so.

**View** CallManagement.cshtml

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ConfirmationDaysOutToPerform, "Spinbox")
```

**Template** Spinbox.cshtml

```
@Html.Infragistics().NumericEditorFor(m => ViewData.ModelMetadata).ButtonType(TextEditorButtonType.Spin).Render()
```

Basically I have a lot of these spinboxes that I want a custom template for and I have to use this Infragistics control. However, I have to pass in the property to leverage property data annotations for validation. Without the use of a template I'm afraid I'll have a lot of redundant html as well as javascript code.

Comment: Yes, but its just `NumericEditorFor(m =>m)` assuming you have defined the model correctly in the template

Comment: That worked. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your template needs to access the model (not `ViewData.ModelMetadata`)

```
@Html.Infragistics().NumericEditorFor(m => m).ButtonType(TextEditorButtonType.Spin).Render()
```